# Allowing only one select option of a certain value to be selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a jsfiddle for this at http://jsfiddle.net/MZtML/

I have a row of images with a select box to determine what type of image it is. These are the options:

```
<select name="image-type">
    <option value="none">Select Image Type</option>
    <option value="small-thumbnail">Small Thumbnail (70x50)</option>
    <option value="thumbnail" selected="selected">Thumbnail (140x100)</option>
    <option value="feature">Feature</option>
    <option value="gallery">Gallery</option>
</select>
```

Now when there are several rows of images, I only want to allow one row to be designated as Feature. If another row is currently set as Feature it should be reset to Select Image Type. The same with Small Thumbnail and Thumbnail.

There can be multiple images set as Select Image Type and as Gallery.

I've been trying using the follow jQuery:

```
$('#image_container').on('change', '[name="image-type"]', function() {
    $this = $(this);

    $('[name="image-type"]').not($this).each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === 'feature') {
            $(this).val('none');
        }
    });
});
```

I've tried a few variations of this and I have gotten close, but nothing I've tried seems to do it accurately. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**updated jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MZtML/10/)

A couple of things:

You had the container area wrong in the fiddle, you needed: `#image_library`. Also if you want the value of selected option you need to do: `$(this).find('option:selected').val()`.

```
$('#image_library').on('change', '[name="image-type"]', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        _current = $(this).find('option:selected').val(); // save current val

    // we're only allowing 'gallery' to have multiple

    if (_current !== 'gallery') {

        // loop through all selects to remove any matching values
        $('[name="image-type"]').not($this).each(function() {

            if ($(this).find('option:selected').val() === _current) {
                $(this).val('');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

​

Comment: I actually tried something like this before and got the same issue in this jsfiddle. Set one of the options to Feature then select another as Small Thumbnail. It will reset the Feature one to Select Image Type. I can't figure out why it's doing that.

Comment: Just updated it! Completely forgot to make sure the current one is "featured" before needing to loop through and remove any other ones that have it. Fixed :)

Comment: This one should be marked as the Answer, as it meets all of the requirements, whereas I missed the Gallery req.

Answer (score 2):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MZtML/7/)

Building off of @mcpDESIGNS fine work, I removed the hard-coded `"feature"` value and instead got the value of the currently selected option. Then you can iterate through the other drop-downs and compare accordingly.

Note that without the `var` keyword, your `$this` variable is scoped to the global.

```
$('#image_library').on('change', '[name="image-type"]', function() {
    // without the var, you're creating a global variable $this...
    var $this = $(this),
        thisValue = $this.find('option:selected').val();

    // using find() with an id context is faster
    $('#image_library').find('[name="image-type"]').not($this).each(function() {
        //console.log($(this).find('option:selected').val());
        if ($(this).find('option:selected').val() === thisValue) {
            $(this).val('');
        }
    });
});
```

​

Comment: +1 Very true! Didn't notice he wanted any of them to match up. Just updated mine with this too... Nothing can have more than 1 except for Gallery